# Connection timed out & MySQL server has gone away with innodb engine

Tags: mysql-5.6, my.cnf

I have created chat application which ping server every sec for messages. Currently I have done load test with httperf, with 500 request/sec.
 **"Connection timed out & MySQL server has gone away with innodb engine"**.

```
my.cnf has following configuration
query_cache_type=1
key_buffer_size=384M
query_cache_size=64M
back_log=500
join_buffer_size=1M
query_prealloc_size=150K
sort_buffer_size=16M
read_buffer_size=2M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
key_cache_age_threshold=3000
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 8
innodb_buffer_pool_size=8G
innodb_log_file_size=200M
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_io_capacity=2000
innodb_io_capacity_max=6000
innodb_lru_scan_depth=2000
max_connections=2000
```

Following are the timeout variable,
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name                  | Value             | 
+---------------------------------+-------------------+
| binlog_max_flush_queue_time     | 0                 |
| connect_timeout                 | 10                |
| datetime_format                 | %Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s |
| delayed_insert_timeout          | 300               |
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | OFF               |
| flush_time                      | 0                 |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout     | 1                 |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout        | 50                |
| innodb_old_blocks_time          | 1000              |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout      | OFF               |
| interactive_timeout             | 28800             |
| lc_time_names                   | en_US             |
| lock_wait_timeout               | 31536000          |
| long_query_time                 | 10.000000         |
| net_read_timeout                | 30                |
| net_write_timeout               | 60                |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout          | 31536000          |
| slave_net_timeout               | 3600              |
| slow_launch_time                | 2                 |
| system_time_zone                | UTC               |
| time_format                     | %H:%i:%s          |
| time_zone                       | SYSTEM            |
| timed_mutexes                   | OFF               |
| wait_timeout                    | 28800             |
+---------------------------------+-------------------+

Comment: what are timeout variables values? use show variables like '%time%'; and see the respective values for timeout session variables

Comment: @NawazSohail I have above mentioned time parameter configured